# Simple Harmonic Oscillation of a vertical Spring

Tags: forces, harmonic-oscillator, spring, equilibrium

If a spring with a  spring constant of k is hung vertically, and a mass is attached to it the spring will rest in equilibrium at some distance h from the springs original equilibrium length because the spring force must equal the gravitational force. Now lets say I pull the mass down some distance, and I let go, obviously, it will begin to oscillate. But, I am confused whether the center of oscillation will be at distance h, or about the spring's original equilibrium length.

Comment: -1 Why don't you get hold of a spring or elastic band and try it?

Answer (score 0):

It will be about the lower point.

Imagine the spring is 10 meters long hanging from a tree branch 16 meters off the ground (so the end of the spring is 6 meters up). You climb up a ladder and add a large mass to the spring, stretching it by 5 meters, to 15 meters in total length.  It's resting there quietly, one meter off the ground. Then you pull the mass down 1 centimeter, and let it go.  What happens?  Does it jump back up to 6 meters in the air?